# Explode data and build new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7.3

I need to explode the key values of an array and build a new array which has the exploded result. Below code works with one sub-array and I think I am missing a for loop to take care of the array values iteration.

The solution should also process the 'finance' subarray data, to be exploded and visible in the new array.

I would have 9 sub-arrays in later stage, thus the reason of needing to explode the data and move result into new array.

**My code**

```
<?php

$array = [
  'company_info' => [
    'country_period_0'  => 10,
    'currency_period_0' => 20
  ],
  'finance'      => [
    'values_period_0' => 30
  ]
];

$newArray = [];

for ($i=0; $i <= 1 ; $i++) {

  $array_1     = $array['company_info'];
  $arrayKeys   = array_keys($array_1);
  $arrayValues = array_values($array_1);

  $keySplits   = explode("_", $arrayKeys[$i]);

  for ($i=0; $i <= 2 ; $i++) {
    $newArray[] = $keySplits[$i];
  }
    $newArray[3] = $arrayValues[0];

}

print_r($newArray);
```

**Result**

```
Array(
    [0] => country
    [1] => period
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 10
)
```

**Wanted result**

```
['company_info]
Array(
    [0] => country
    [1] => period
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 10
)
Array(
    [0] => currency
    [1] => period
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 20
)
['finance']
Array(
    [0] => values
    [1] => period
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 30
)
```

Comment: You kept the same variable as iterator, `$i` in both outer and inner `for` loop. In the inner loop, it increases `$i` at a point it reached the max value of the outer one (`$i <= 1`). This won't fix your whole code, but this is a good start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it a lot using `foreach` loops, especially fetching the key each time along with the value to help with the array building.

This also uses `explode()` and adds the result to the `$newArray` with the key from the first level using `$newArray[$mainKey][]`, but also just adds the value to the end of the array using `[]`...

```
foreach ( $array as $mainKey => $elements )  {
    foreach ( $elements as $subKey => $value ){
        $newData = explode("_", $subKey);
        $newData[] = $value;
        $newArray[$mainKey][] = $newData;
    }
}
```

with your test data gives...

```
Array
(
    [company_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => country
                    [1] => period
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 10
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => currency
                    [1] => period
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 20
                )

        )

    [finance] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => values
                    [1] => period
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 30
                )

        )

)
```

I just noticed that I was missing the second `company_info` data, so this means the values will always be arrays, unless you really need them only to be arrays when needed.

Comment: It is totally fine that the result stays as array, since I plan to iterated over the data in later stage.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_array=[];
foreach($array as $category => $tmp ){

  foreach($tmp as $key => $value){
    $exp = explode('_', $key);
    $exp[] = $value;
    $new_array[ $category ][] = $exp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanations isn't welcome and doesn't help at all. *"Give a man a program, he will suffer one day. Teach him how to program and he will suffer everyday"*

Comment: @Michel Your suggestion works fine. Please update the answer with some explanation and I will go ahead and approve the answer. For more people to understand your answer and logic I think also you could slightly expand the name convention used, e.g. $exp

Comment: Upvoting code-only answers sends a bad message.

Comment: Sorry guys, typed the code and had to go in a hurry. Will update today.